# HP 8568B J1 Connector identification

Tags: identification, connector, spectrum-analyzer, cable-assemblies

Can anyone identify these 4 individual RF connectors? I think it's some sort of RP-SMB, but it could be something more foreign. I would need to buy 4 cables to connect up the spectrum analyzer.

[image: HP8568B J1 connector]

Digging through ebay, the expected connector looks like this:

[image]

The original cable is HP P/N 85662-60093, and costs wayyyy too much for a cable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connector looks like a variant of 13W3 which was used by professional workstations with high resolution analog monitors before LCDs entered the scene. The round connectors are true coax for high frequency with proper impedance and proper shielding as opposed to DB15.

Image from Wikipedia:
[image]

If you search for the connector type, you should be able to find a 5 coax variant of it.

Found by OP: It’s DB-5W5. https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Amphenol-FCI/DBO5W5S500G30LF?qs=1Qbx6cv8UfUX9x4NKVoy8w%3D%3D